# How do you create a method to throw an exception in java?

Tags: java, exception

My homework says we must follow these instructions to create the `throwException` method.

throwException method

- Should take in an Exception object as its only parameter and return nothing
- Take that exception and throw it

How do you create this method?

What I have so far is:

```
public void throwException (Exception ex) throws Exception {
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried anything yet? How would you start?

Comment: Study:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: You simply `throw` it.

Comment: Bizarre and pointless homework, but a good question because it's specific, answerable, and the asker admits it's homework.

Answer (score 2):

Your current method covers the first point - to take an exception as parameter.
The `throws Exception` is unnecessary if you dont throw it from a method, but it is needed to cover the second point.

As commenters pointed, you just need to use the `throw` keyword to ***throw*** an exception, so the method could look like:

```
public void throwException (Exception ex) throws Exception {
    //some other code maybe?
    throw ex;
}
```

This implementation has a little flaw. When the `null` is passed as a parameter to it, the method will throw a NullPointerException, because the `throw` keyword accepts objects of the Throwable class or its subclasses (Exception is a subclass of Throwable).
To avoid NullPointerException (which is an unchecked-exception), simple `if` statement can be used:

```
public void throwException (Exception ex) throws Exception {
    if (ex != null) {
        throw ex;
    }
    //just for presentation,below it throws new Exception
    throw new Exception("ex parameter was null");
}
```

Edit:
As @Slaw suggested, in that very small case adding the null-check and throwing new Exception just disguises the NullPointerException. Without the null-check and `throw new...` the NPE will be thrown from that method and its stacktrace will show exact line of `throw ex` when the null is passed to that method.
The NPE is a subtype of RuntimeException class and the subtypes of RuntimeException doesn't need to be explicitly declared in method signature when they are thrown from that method. Like here:

```
public static void throwNPE(Exception e) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

The RuntimeException and its subclasses are called an unchecked-exceptions.  Other classes extending one of Exception or Throwable classes are call checked-exceptions, because if a method throws them, it must declare that exception (or superclass) in the signature or explicitly try-catch it.

The proper use of null-check would be when the method would throw a more specific kind of exception (like IOException or a new subclass of Exception/Throwable) and the when the other method using the one which throws that new type of Exception would try-catch that specific type the NPE wouldn't be caught.

Just for good practices, when dealing with try-catch it's much better to catch exact types of thrown Exceptions instead of general Exception/Throwable. It helps to understand the real cause of exception, debug and fix code.

Comment: You explained so much better than my professor. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure the null-check provides any value. You're essentially throwing a `NullPointerException` but disguised as a different exception type.

Comment: @Slaw you're right, I was thinking of situation when OP will start creating his own types of exceptions and throwing that new type from a method (where the signature would point that type), so NPE wouldn't be covered.